# Оконные приложения Windows на Visual Studio 13 Ultimate и C++

Tags: windows, графика, visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы узнать как реализовать оконные приложения Windows на Visual Studio 13 Ultimate и C++. Без использования Qt, только средствами студии.  Что сейчас актуально? Есть ли какой-нибудь мануал?

Comment: Пакет Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC)?

Answer (score 2):

Пакет Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC).

Вот [мануал](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/visualc/mfc/).
Вот [книга](http://www.realcoding.net/articles/visual-c-i-mfc-rukovodstvo-dlya-professionalov.html).

Comment: А CLR не актуальнее?

Comment: А какое отношение к "оконным приложениям" имеет CLR? Да и человек же спрашивает о C++, а не о managed вещах. Тога уже давайте советовать WPF или WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, недавно отвечали:
[Легковесные GUI-приложения](/questions/404337/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-gui-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 1):

> Хотелось бы узнать как реализовать оконные приложения Windows на Visual Studio 13 Ultimate 
> и C++. Без использования Qt, только средствами студии

Либо MFC, либо WinAPI в чистом виде.

> Есть ли какой-нибудь мануал?

MCF очень низкоуровневый и сложный фреймворк, поэтому одним мануалом здесь не отделаешься, к тому же, изучая его вам придется не один раз заглядывать в справочник по WinAPI. Одной из лучших книг по Visual C++ и MFC является книга Девида Круглински "Программирование на Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0". Ее можно легко найти в сети.

Параллельно, рекомендую читать книгу Рихтера "Windows для профессионалов: создание эффективных Win32 приложений с учетом специфики 64 разрядной версии Windows", т.к. MFC - это очень "легкий" слой абстракции над "голым" WinAPI. И вам таки придется разобраться в некоторых основах работы ОС, например, в том как работает петля обработки сообщений в программах и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен чистый C++, то кроме WinAPI и MFC из коробки ничего более нет, это тот еще мазахизм. Есть мазохизм и с другой стороны, это использование C++/Cli.